# R Reshape Many Stubs in DPLYR or DATA.TABLE

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

This is my data

```
STUDENT CLASS   TIME_1  TIME_2  math1   math2   hist1   hist2
1   90  119 106 4   6   3   10
2   8       115 4   7       2
3   3   74  112 5   7   8   10
```

and I wish to make this file from wide to long to

```
STUDENT CLASS   TIME    math    hist
1   90  119 4   3
1   90  106 6   10
2   8       4   2
2   8   115 7   
3   3   74  5   8
3   3   112 7   10
```

I tried,

```
melt(setDT(DATA), measure = patterns("TIME_", "math", "hist"), variable.name = 'var', value.name = c('TIME_', 'math', 'hist')
```

with no success

Comment: Can you provide reproducible data: `dput(mydata)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Setting the second argument in `names_to` to `NA` drops the unwanted column:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(STUDENT, CLASS), 
               names_to = c(".value", NA), 
               names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
```

Output

```
  STUDENT CLASS TIME_  math  hist
    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       1    90   119     4     3
2       1    90   106     6    10
3       2     8    NA     4    NA
4       2     8   115     7     2
5       3     3    74     5     8
6       3     3   112     7    10
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "STUDENT CLASS   TIME_1  TIME_2  math1   math2   hist1   hist2
1   90  119 106 4   6   3   10
2   8   NA    115 4   7   NA    2
3   3   74  112 5   7   8   10", h = TRUE)

df_want <- read.table(text = "STUDENT CLASS   TIME    math    hist
1   90  119 4   3
1   90  106 6   10
2   8     NA  4   2
2   8   115 7   NA
3   3   74  5   8
3   3   112 7   10", h = TRUE)
```